# How to remove a shared view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Hello I added a `UIView` to my `ViewController` in this way.

```
self.vWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    let mainBound = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width, 135)//CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 135.0)
    let lblVideo = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 50))
    lblVideo.text = "Videos"
    lblVideo.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    self.vwVideo = UIView.init(frame: mainBound)
    self.vwVideo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    vWindow!.addSubview(self.vwVideo)
```

When I go to particular `ViewController` from this `ViewController` I want to remove this bottom view.I did `self.vwVideo.removeFromSuperview()` in `viewDidDissappear()` but it doesn't remove my bottom view. How can I do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with:

```
self.vWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
let mainBound = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-50, self.view.frame.size.width,135)
//CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 135.0)
let lblVideo = UILabel.init(frame: CGRectMake(10, 0, 100, 50))
lblVideo.text = "Videos"
lblVideo.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
self.vwVideo = UIView.init(frame: mainBound)
self.vwVideo.tag = 666 // You must tag your video to find after and to destroy it
self.vwVideo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
vWindow!.addSubview(self.vwVideo)
```

After, when you want to destroy your view it's enough to do:

```
self.vWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
self.vWindow!.viewWithTag(666).removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also declare your label as a global outlet, in a .swift file right below your **import** statements:

```
var lblVideo = UILabel()
```

then you can use `lblVideo.removeFromSuperview()` in viewDidDisappear()